# Trouble with Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

So I'm new to using reflection and I'm getting inconsistent results.

First I tried converting this line to reflection

```
userForm.setEquipment(currentForm.getFirstEquipment);
```

This is what I did and it seems to work.

```
try{
    Method setObject = userForm.getClass().getMethod("setObject", Shipment.class);
    setObject.invoke(userForm, currentForm.getFirstObject());
}
catch ( Exception e){
    Logger.error(e);
}
```

But when I tried something similar with a different line it doesn't work.

Here's what I started with.

```
List<Shipment> list = new ArrayList<Shipment>();
list.add(userForm.getFirstObject);
```

and this is what I have now, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
List<Shipment> list = new ArrayList<Shipment>();
try{
    Method add = list.getClass().getMethod("add", Shipment.class);
    add.invoke(list, userForm.getFirstObject());
}
catch ( Exception e){
    Logger.error(e);
}
```

Comment: Add the code for `Shipment` class

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a useful description.

Answer (score 1):

`List` does not have a `add(Shipment)` method. It does have a `add(T)` one though. But because of type erasure type information is lost. To resolve the method use this line:

```
list.getClass().getMethod("add", Object.class)
```